# How to make a piece of code to be executed only after the line before? (Android C#)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I need to make a loader to start animatin before the rest of the code to be executed.

I have my code and it says loader.Animate() and then do the stuff that takes 4 seconds to be done. But the problem is that even puttin the loader.Animate() before the rest of the code the animation starts only after all that stuff is done, its like the screen freezes.

What would be the best way i can make this right like start animating and only after do the rest. I tried using Thread.Sleep but didnt worked.

Comment: You should consider moving whatever you need to do into a seperate worker thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the use cases where async await is great. Here is a quick sample that should give you an idea how to use it:

```
    protected override async void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume ();

        StartAnimate ();

        await RunAsync (TimeSpan.FromSeconds (4));

        StopAnimate ();
    }

    private async Task RunAsync(TimeSpan span)
    {
        await Task.Delay (span);
    }

    private void StartAnimate()
    {
        // put animation here
    }

    private void StopAnimate()
    {
        // stop animating after the thread has ended
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use multithreading. Do your "work" in a different thread than you do your "graphics work".

Comment: The problem is that i cant go ahead without using that code that takes 4 seconds to go. And i cant run loader animate from another thread... :/

Comment: You have to run the 4 seconds code in another thread, and the loader animation in the main thread

Comment: I already got it man but if i run this 4 second code async the app doesnt wait the 4 seconds and jump to the next screen before finishing that process and bugs... I need at least a response or something

Comment: You could go separate routes at this point. Perhaps try Thread.Join to make sure your work thread is complete. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta(v=vs.110).aspx